# Is this true for chromatic numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

If we take the graph $G=(V(G),E(G))$ and partition the edges $E(G)$ into $k$ sets, forming $k$ subgraphs of the form $H_i=(V(G),E(H_i))$ for $i\in\{1,...,k\}$ such that $|E(H_i)|\ge 1$ for each subgraph $H_i$. Furthermore, we let $\chi(G)$ be the chromatic number of the graph $G$.

Does it hold that $\prod_{i=1}^{k}\chi(H_i)\ge \chi(G)$?  How would we prove it? I know that this holds when $k=2$. How about other values $k\ge 3$?

For the case $k=2$ we can take $H,\overline{H}\subseteq G$ such that $H=(V(G),E(H))$ and $\overline{H}=(V(G),E\setminus E(H))$. If the coloring $C_H:V(G)\rightarrow [\chi(H)]$ is a coloring of $H$ and $C_{\overline{H}}:V(G)\rightarrow [\chi(\overline{H})]$ is a coloring of $\overline{H}$, we are able to construct a coloring $C_G$ of $G$ with at most $\chi(H)\cdot \chi(\overline{H})$ colors by letting $C_{G}(v)=(C_{H}(v),C_{\overline{H}}(v))$. We can also observe that every edge $(u,v)$ in $G$ belongs to either $H$ or $\overline{H}$ and hence $C_{G}(u)$ differs from $C_{G}(v)$ in at least one of the coordinates.

Can this same argument potentially be generalized for the case of partitioning $G$ into $k$ subgraphs such that $|E(H_i)|\ge 1$ for each subgraph?

Comment: For $k=3$, can we apply the initial case ($k=2$) to $H_1$ and $H_2$ and then to $H_1\cup H_2$ and $H_3$ and use induction of this sort for the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the exact same argument works for $k \geq 3$. Take a coloring $C_{H_i} : V(G) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}_i$ of each $H_i$ where $|\mathcal{C}_i| = \chi(H_i)$. Then we can construct a coloring $C : V(G) \rightarrow \prod_i \mathcal{C}_i$ by setting $$ C(v) = (C_{H_{1}}(v),C_{H_2}(v),\ldots,C_{H_k}(v)) \hskip{2em} \forall v \in V(G).$$ As before, if an edge $uv$ is in $H_i$, then $C(u)$ and $C(v)$ will differ in the $i$-th coordinate, so this is a proper coloring of $G$ with $\prod_i \chi(H_i)$ colors.